# Build custom input field list with display field from associated model in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I have three tables `campaign_social_accounts`, `social_accounts`, and `social_networks`

`SocialNetworks` contains are networks which user can connect to with columns as

```
+-----+--------+
| id  | title  |
+-----+--------+
```

`SocialAccounts` has the all accounts user is connected to with columns as

```
+----+---------+-------------------+--------------+----------+
| id | user_id | social_network_id | access_token | user_key |
+----+---------+-------------------+--------------+----------+
```

`CampaignSocialAccounts` has association of `Campaigns` and added social accounts to that campaign

```
+-----+-------------+-------------------+
| id  | campaign_id | social_account_id |
+-----+-------------+-------------------+
```

In `add()` of `CampaignSocialAccounts` I want user to select from `SocialAccounts` for that, this is what I have done in controller

```
$socialAccounts = $this->CampaignSocialAccounts->SocialAccounts->find('list', [
   'conditions' => [
       'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
   ]
]);
```

and `add.ctp`

```
echo $this->Form->control('social_account_id', ['options' => $socialAccounts]);
```

**Question**

This shows `id` in the list as there is no other column in that field that can be set to `displayField()`

Also, I want to display list somewhat like

```
Facebook(112233445566)
Youtube(2233112233)
```

Where `Facebook` and `Youtube` are title from `SocialNetworks` table and `(112233....)` is `user_key` from `SocialAccounts` and the value of the option generated will be the `id` of the `SocialAccounts`

```
<option value="1<id from social_accounts>">Facebook(112233445566)</option>
<option value="2<id from social_accounts>">Youtube(2233112233)</option>
```

**Is it possible, if yes, what is the best and simple approach to do this.**

> Edit 2: My Try

In controller action

```
$socialAccounts = $this->CampaignSocialAccounts->SocialAccounts
    ->find('list', ['valueKey' => 'social_account_title'])
    ->contain(['SocialNetworks'])
    ->where(['user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')]);
```

SocialAccount.php entity

```
public function _getSocialAccountTitle()
{
    if (isset($this->social_network)) {
        return $this->social_network->title.' ('.$this->user_key.')';
    }
    return $this->id;
}
```

**Still no effect**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `SocialAccounts` Entity you can define a virtual property

```
public function _getFullName()
{
    if(isset($this->social_network))
        return $this->social_network->name.' ('.$this->user_key.')';
    return $this->id;
}
```

then tu can use your new virtual property in the find() call

in your controller

```
$socialAccounts = $this->CampaignSocialAccounts->SocialAccounts
    ->find('list', ['valueField' => 'full_name'])
    ->contain(['SocialNetworks'])
    ->where(['user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')]);
```

Comment: see edit 2, I tried what you said. Still displaying `id` only